# After uploading images and resizing with php, the uploaded images are black

Tags: php, image, upload

I usually use this code to upload images and it worked correctly, but a few days ago it started to give me problems on a new server, when loading images especially jpeg images or images from an iphone or mac the image it loads is completely black.
Change the dimensions correctly but the image is black.

It is a code that I used to upload images with php in several of my prolific school and personal, that worked without problems before.
So I don't know if it's because of a change in the PHP version

```
<?php
$exp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    if($_FILES['image']['name'] != ""){ // El campo foto contiene una imagen...
        // Primero, hay que validar que se trata de un JPG/GIF/PNG
        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "JPG", "GIF", "PNG");
        $extension = end($exp);
        if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
                && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
            // el archivo es un JPG/GIF/PNG, entonces...
            $extension = end($exp);
            $foto = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,10).".".$extension;
            $directorio = "CLIENTES"; // directorio de tu elección
            // almacenar imagen en el servidor
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $directorio.'/'.$foto);
            $resFoto = 'res_'.$foto;
            resizeImagen($directorio.'/', $foto, 500, 500,$resFoto,$extension);
            unlink($directorio.'/'.$foto);
            $_SESSION['ERROR']="Se cargo correctamente !!!";
            $OK="1";
        } else { // El archivo no es JPG/GIF/PNG
            $OK="0";
            $_SESSION['ERROR']="No tiene un formato compatible !!!";
          }
    } else { // El campo foto NO contiene una imagen
        $OK="0";
        $_SESSION['ERROR']="No se selecciono archivo!!!";
    }


####
## Función para redimencionar las imágenes
## utilizando las liberías de GD de PHP
####

function resizeImagen($ruta, $nombre, $alto, $ancho,$nombreN,$extension){
    $rutaImagenOriginal = $ruta.$nombre;
    if($extension == 'GIF' || $extension == 'gif'){
    $img_original = imagecreatefromgif($rutaImagenOriginal);
    }
    if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'JPG'){
    $img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagenOriginal);
    }
    if($extension == 'png' || $extension == 'PNG'){
    $img_original = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagenOriginal);
    }
    $max_ancho = $ancho;
    $max_alto = $alto;
    list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rutaImagenOriginal);
    $x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
    $y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;
    if( ($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) ){//Si ancho 
    $ancho_final = $ancho;
        $alto_final = $alto;
    } elseif (($x_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto){
        $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
        $ancho_final = $max_ancho;
    } else{
        $ancho_final = ceil($y_ratio * $ancho);
        $alto_final = $max_alto;
    }
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$img_original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);
    imagedestroy($img_original);
    $calidad=70;
    imagejpeg($tmp,$ruta.$nombreN,$calidad);

}

$img=$directorio;
$img.="/";
$img.=$resFoto;
?>
```

The only mistake I have is that, the loaded image is completely black.

Comment: *.jpeg, you allow them to be uploaded but your `resizeImagen()` does not handle them properly

Comment: I have updated the code as follows:

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "JPG", "GIF", "PNG", "JFIF", "jfif");

                || ($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/jfif"))
.....

if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'JPG' || $extension == 'JPEG' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'JFIF' || $extension == 'jfif'){

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I was facing when I was doing this kind of work. I was using this class:

```
class ResizeImage extends MX_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    var $image;
    var $image_type;

    static function makeDir($path) {
        return is_dir($path) ||  mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }

    function load($filename) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->image_type = $image_info[2];

        if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        } 
    } 

    function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

       // do this or they'll all go to jpeg
       $image_type=$this->image_type;

       if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
           imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
       } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
           imagegif($this->image,$filename);  
       } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
           // need this for transparent png to work          
           imagealphablending($this->image, false);
           imagesavealpha($this->image,true);
           imagepng($this->image,$filename);
    }   

    if( $permissions != null) {
     chmod($filename,$permissions);
    }
}  

function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
        imagejpeg($this->image);
    } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
        imagegif($this->image);
    } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        imagepng($this->image);
    } 
} 

function getWidth() {
    return imagesx($this->image);
} 

function getHeight() {
    return imagesy($this->image);
} 

function resizeToHeight($height) {
    $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
    $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
    $this->resize($width,$height);
}   

function resizeToWidth($width) {
    $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
    $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
    $this->resize($width,$height);
}   

function scale($scale) {
    $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
    $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
    $this->resize($width,$height);
}   

// function resize1($width,$height,$forcesize='n') {
//   /* optional. if file is smaller, do not resize. */
//     if ($forcesize == 'n') {
//       if ($width > $this->getWidth() && $height > $this->getHeight()){
//           $width = $this->getWidth();
//           $height = $this->getHeight();
//       }
//     }

//     $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
//     /* Check if this image is PNG or GIF, then set if Transparent*/  
//     if(($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($this->image_type==IMAGETYPE_PNG)){
//         imagealphablending($new_image, false);
//         imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
//         $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
//         imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
//     }
//     imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

//     $this->image = $new_image;   
// }
function resize($width,$height,$forcesize='n') {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $transparent=imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127));
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->image = $new_image;
}  

}#End of ResizeImage class
```

SO I commented resize1() function and created new resize() function. please check if it can also help you.